# "Error while reading data" error received when uploading CSV file into BigQuery via console UI

Tags: google-bigquery

I need to upload a CSV file to BigQuery via the UI, after I select the file from my local drive I specify BigQuery to automatically detect the Schema and run the job. It fails with the following message:

> "Error while reading data, error message: CSV table encountered too
>   many errors, giving up. Rows: 2; errors: 1. Please look into the
>   errors[] collection for more details."

I have tried removing the comma in the last column, and tried changing options in the advanced section but it always results in the same error.

The error log is not helping me understand where the problem is, this is example of the error log entry:

2

> 019-04-03 23:03:50.261 CLST Bigquery jobcompleted
>   bquxjob_6b9eae1_169e6166db0 frank@xxxxxxxxx.nn INVALID_ARGUMENT

and:

> "Error while reading data, error message: CSV table encountered too
>   many errors, giving up. Rows: 2; errors: 1. Please look into the
>   errors[] collection for more details."

and:

> "Error while reading data, error message: Error detected while parsing
>   row starting at position: 46. Error: Data between close double quote
>   (") and field separator."

The strange thing is that the sample CSV data has NO double quote field separator!?

```
2019-01-02 00:00:00,326,1,,292,0,,294,0,,-28,0,,262,0,,109,0,,372,0,,453,0,,536,0,,136,0,,2609,0,,1450,0,,352,0,,-123,0,,17852,0,,8528,0
2019-01-02 00:02:29,289,1,,402,0,,165,0,,-218,0,,150,0,,90,0,,263,0,,327,0,,275,0,,67,0,,4863,0,,2808,0,,124,0,,454,0,,21880,0,,6410,0
2019-01-02 00:07:29,622,1,,135,0,,228,0,,-147,0,,130,0,,51,0,,381,0,,428,0,,276,0,,67,0,,2672,0,,1623,0,,346,0,,-140,0,,23962,0,,10759,0
2019-01-02 00:12:29,206,1,,118,0,,431,0,,106,0,,133,0,,50,0,,380,0,,426,0,,272,0,,63,0,,1224,0,,740,0,,371,0,,-127,0,,27758,0,,12187,0
2019-01-02 00:17:29,174,1,,119,0,,363,0,,59,0,,157,0,,67,0,,381,0,,426,0,,344,0,,161,0,,923,0,,595,0,,372,0,,-128,0,,22249,0,,9278,0
2019-01-02 00:22:29,175,1,,119,0,,301,0,,7,0,,124,0,,46,0,,382,0,,425,0,,431,0,,339,0,,1622,0,,1344,0,,379,0,,-126,0,,23888,0,,8963,0
```

I shared an example of a few lines of CSV data. I expect BigQuery to be able to detect the schema and load the data into a new table.

Comment: The few lines you shared is working fine. maybe issue in remaining data

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using BigQuery [new WebUI](https://console.cloud.google.com/bigquery) and your input data I did the following:

1. Select a dataset
2. Clicked on create a table
3. Filled the create table form as follow:

[image]

4. The table was created and I was able to `SELECT` 6 rows as expected

   SELECT * FROM `projectId.datasetId.SO` LIMIT 1000

[image]

Comment: Thank you, I retried this from google drive and now it is working. Thank you for your time!  I think it must have been a temporary error in BQ because I did exactly the same thing as you did!

Comment: Happy to hear that, Will be great if you can accept and vote-up this answer for others to see.

Comment: @Frank thank you but looks like you didn't accepted the answer.  To do this you can mark accepted answer by using the tick on the left of the posted answer, below the voting. See https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work#5235 (Voting up is a different action, see this link https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers)

Answer (score 0):

*Set Quote Character to 'None' it would solve the problem*

[[image: img]]][1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XmIjc.png)

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).